# Is there a way to upload mobileApp files, or files in general without using Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-files, microsoft-graph-intune

As the title reads, currently our organization doesn't have Azure Storage as an option for our developers. However, we are trying to automate and streamline our iOS and Android deployments into Intune using Microsoft's Graph API.

Currently we have tried looking at different ways or alternatives to get around this, but it doesn't seem like there is any documentation supported to try and upload the binaries without using Azure Storage. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upload files to Microsoft Intune using the Create upload session API in Microsoft Graph. This allows you to upload mobile app package files, such as APK for Android or IPA for iOS, without the need for Azure Storage.

Here are the steps:

1. Create an upload session: You need to call the createUploadSession action on a mobileApp content version to start a new upload session.

   ```
    POST /deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/{mobileAppId}/mobileAppContent/{mobileAppContentId}/createUploadSession
   ```
2. Upload bytes to the upload session: After you've started an upload session, you can use the uploadUrl value from the response of createUploadSession to upload the file bytes. You need to use a PUT request to upload the file.
3. Commit the upload session: Once the upload is complete, you need to call the commit action on the mobileAppContent record to finalize the upload and enable the content for assignments.

   ```
    POST /deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/{mobileAppId}/mobileAppContent/{mobileAppContentId}/commit
   ```

Please read more on how to create upload sessions using MS Graph from this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0).